# Pipedrive multiple filters

Tags: pipedrive-api

I am currently working on an integration that involves filtering persons based on multiple fields and multiple values per field, through the API.

As far as I know, it is not possible to implement the following type of filter using the API:

- Custom Field A with an "OR" operator between the options: option-1 OR option-2 OR option-3
  "AND"
- Custom Field B with an "OR" operator between the options: option-4 OR option-5 OR option-6
  "AND"
- Custom Field C with an "OR" operator between the options: option-7 OR option-8 OR option-9

Could you kindly confirm if this type of filter is not supported by the API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using filters in combination with the Pipedrive CRM API will optimize your data retrieval process

**Step 1: Create a Filter**

A filter of the same kind can be applied when fetching a list of deals, leads, persons, organizations or products in the context of a pipeline. Filters are limited to a maximum of 16 conditions

**Step 2: Obtain the Filter ID**

Once the filter is set up, obtain its unique identifier, the filter_id. This ID will be used to identify the filter and retrieve the data matching its criteria.

You can check API Filter here: https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1/Filters#getFilters

**Step 3: Make API Requests**

Get the deals with filter_id you got on step 2

https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1/Deals#getDeals

Hope that can help you